# Spotfire DenseRank by category, do I use OVER?

Tags: spotfire, rank

I'm trying to rank some data in spotfire, and I'm having a bit of trouble writing a formula to calculate it. Here's a breakdown of what I am working with.

Group: the test group

SNP: what SNP I am looking at

Count: how many counts I get for the specific SNP

What I'd like to do is rank the average # of counts that are present for each SNP, within the group. Thus, I could then see, within a group, which SNP ranks #1, #2, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR Disclaimer:** You can do this, though if you are changing your cross table frequently, it may become a giant hassle.  Make sure to double-check that logic is what you'd expect after any modification.  *Proceed with caution.*

The basis of the Custom Expression you seem to be looking for is as follows:

```
Max(DenseRank(Count() OVER (Intersect([Group],[SNP])),"desc",[Group]))
```

<sub>This gives the total count of rows instead of the average; I was uncertain if "Count" was supposed to be a column or not.  If you really do want to turn it into an average, make sure to adjust accordingly.</sub>
If all you have is the Group and the SNP nested on the left, you're done and good to go.

**First issue**, when you want to filter it down, it gives you the dense rank of only those in the filtered set.  In some cases this is good, and what you're looking for; in others, it isn't.  If you want it to hold fast to its value, regardless of filtering, you can use the same logic, but throw it in a Calculated column, instead of in the custom expression.  Then, in your CrossTable Aggregation, get the max of the Calculated Column value.

Calculated Column:

```
DenseRank(Count() OVER (Intersect([Group],[SNP])),"desc",[Group])
```

**Second Issue:**  You want to pivot by something other than Group and SNP.  Perhaps, for example, by date?  If you throw the Date across the top, it's going to show the same numbers for every month -- the overall numbers.  This is not particularly helpful.

To a certain extent, Spotfire's Custom Expressions can handle this modification.  If you switch between using a single column, you could use the following:

```
Max(DenseRank(Count() OVER (Intersect([${Axis.Columns.ShortDisplayName}],[Group],[SNP])),"desc",[Group],[${Axis.Columns.ShortDisplayName}]))
```

That would automatically pull in the column from the top, and show you the ranking for each individual process date.

However, if you start nesting, using hierarchies, renaming your columns, or having multiple aggregations and throwing (Column Names) across the top, you're going to start having to pay a great deal to your custom expression.  You'll need to do some form of string replacement around the Axis.Column, or use expression instead of Short Names, and get rid of Nests, etc.

Any layer of complexity will require this sort of analysis, so if your end-users have access to modify the pivot table... honestly, I probably wouldn't give them this column.

**Third Issue:** I don't know if this is an issue, exactly, but you said "Average Counts" -- Average per day? Per Month?  
 When averaging, you will need to decide if, for example, a month is the total number of days in month or the number of days that particular payor had data.  However you decide to aggregate it, make sure you're doing it on the right level.

<sub>For the record, I liked the premise of this question; it's something I'd thought would be useful before, but never took the time to try to implement, since sorting a column or limiting a table to only show the top 10 values is much simpler</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments. I followed your instructions and it is working well.